# How do I boot Ubuntu from a partition on an external hard drive after installation?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, external-hdd

I have just finished installing Ubuntu to a 50gb partition of a 1Tb external hard drive. I was able to set up everything perfectly fine within Ubuntu and use it without any problems. Now when I enter the BIOS to select the partition to boot from, the partition isn’t showing up. The hard drive is there and shows its reduced capacity, but the 50Gb partition is not visible to boot from. How do I access it again?

Comment: What brand/model system, what video card/chip? Are you trying to boot from same system or what flexibility to boot from other systems? Do you have an ESP on external drive? Is install UEFI? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/